# How to get product information from remote controller ir(infrared) data?

Tags: c

I have a remote controller of aircon and I have succeed in extracting the ir data of the power button.  The ir data is following:

0x26 0x00 0xf8 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x13 0x89 0x12 0x11
0x12 0x34 0x13 0x33 0x13 0x10 0x13 0x33 0x13 0x11
0x11 0x34 0x14 0x11 0x11 0x35 0x12 0x10 0x13 0x10
0x13 0x11 0x11 0x35 0x13 0x33 0x13 0x34 0x13 0x10
.....  so on and so on.
Now what I want to do is to make c program of getting the product information of this remote controller from this ir data of power button. And I want to get other buttons' ir datas also.

More specifically, I want to make a program that find out the information of the certain product and the infrared code of other buttons with the power button's ir datacode only.

If it is possible, how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may search for IRMP that is a IR multi protocol decoder. Primarily for micro controllers but it also has command line tool that can take decoded ir strings (you may record some more and reformat them) and shows details about the detected protocol (and the data (ids and keycode)).

However - information about the product are not retreived. Never searched if there is any database in the web that collects such data.

edit: 
also english version of the Mikrocontroller.net article is available:

- german: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/IRMP
- english: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/IRMP_-_english#top

Comment: @johncarrie i just saw that frank also provides an english article - added links